# How to direct python to fetch string in a different file

Tags: python, web-scraping

How do I change the "keyword" in parameter ('pegasus') to redirect to a separate text file.
So later I just write whatever items I want to scrape in the file txt. Example of Pegasus, Phoenix, Lucid
then the keyword parameter is directed to a different txt, inside the txt it contains a list of those objects
and once it has finished scraping the pegasus it will scrape next item which is Phoenix, and so on.

```
import requests
import csv

key = input('enter name file u want :')
write = csv.writer(open('output/{}.csv'.format(key), 'w', newline=''))
header = ['Name', 'Price', 'Seller', 'Order']
write.writerow(header)

url = 'https://api-gateway.itemku.com/v1/product'
count = 0
for page in range(1, 2):
parameter = {
    'is_include_game': 1,
    'is_include_item_type': 1,
    'is_include_item_info_group': 0,
    'is_include_order_record': 1,
    'is_from_web': 1,
    'is_include_upselling_product': 1,
    'game_id': 29,
    'per_page': 18,
    'page': page,
    'sort': 'cheap',
    'is_auto_delivery_first': 1,
    'is_with_promotion': 1,
    'keyword': 'pegasus'
}

r = requests.get(url, params=parameter).json()

products = r['data']['data']
for p in products:
    name = p['name']
    price = p['price']
    seller = p['seller']
    order = p['order_record']
    count += 1
    print('No :', count, 'name:', name, 'price:',
          price, 'seller:', seller, 'order:', order)
    write = csv.writer(
        open('output/{}.csv'.format(key), 'a', newline=''))
    data = [name, price, seller, order]
    write.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do i change the "keyword" in parameter ('pegasus')

If you mean changing "value" of key "keyword" inside parameter, then simply replace the value:

```
parameter['keyword'] = "Pheonix"
```

---

To read data from a .txt file and loop through it, just read the file and add the values to list, then loop through it

```
key = [line.strip() for line in open('../relative/path','r')
....
for keyword in key:
    ....
    parameter = {
    'is_include_game': 1,
    'is_include_item_type': 1,
    'is_include_item_info_group': 0,
    'is_include_order_record': 1,
    'is_from_web': 1,
    'is_include_upselling_product': 1,
    'game_id': 29,
    'per_page': 18,
    'page': page,
    'sort': 'cheap',
    'is_auto_delivery_first': 1,
    'is_with_promotion': 1,
    'keyword': keyword
    }

    # or you could set the value after creating parameter dictionary
    # parameter['key'] = keyword
```

Reading a file this way will not close the file after it finished reading, But it shouldn't be a problem unless you use this method to open a lot of files. garbage collector should do the job closing the file for us.

Comment: No i mean change the keyword but the string in diffrent txt file so like. parameter['keyword'] = "file.txt"
Inside that file.txt: 
"Pegasus"
"Phoenix"
"Lucid"

Comment: So what you're meaning to do is read a word (Pegasus, Phoenix, etc) from a file, and change the value using that word?

Comment: yes so the resulting output will match the list I want in file.txt.
previously I wrote one by one in the parameters, for example I want to scrape the pegasus, I write the keyword "pegasus" and run the program, wait for it to finish,
once done i replaced the pegasus with phoenix and so on.
too complex and inefficient, takes a lot of time,
with this possible, I just need to write a list of what I want in a txt file, and only by running the script once the various items I want to scrape can be finished with one scrape. it will be very helpful

Comment: I think reading the text from the file (word separated by \n), storing it as a list, and then looping through it should be enough

Comment: thanks bro very helpful, but I still have a problem, this doesn't want to loop from the first, when I write in the file.txt pegasus phoenix lucid. it just spits out the last word which is lucid. so the output that comes out is only lucid

Comment: my bad. The code in my answer expected the words to be delimited by \n, that is, one word per line.